# How to ignore user code when breaking to point of failure in test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've created a significant number of methods to help me perform unit test assertions in Visual Studio 2010. I've also enabled "Double-click a Failed or Inconclusive unit test result displays the point of failure in the test" option in the Test Execution options. My issue is that with these helper methods, I'd like the point of failure to be the stack frame calling my helper method, not the exception being thrown within the helper method.

Obviously, I can do "ShowDetails" and click higher in the stack, but that will pretty much cancel out any time saved by using the helper method.

I've tried using the various `[Debugger*]`  attributes on my method without success.

Here's some example code to illustrate my issue.

```
public void MyTest()
{
    // ACT
    var res = DoSomething();

    // ASSERT
    AssertDateRange(res, TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
}

public static void AssertDateRange(DateTime value, TimeSpan range)
{
    var difference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(value);
    if (Math.Abs(range.TotalMilliseconds) - Math.Abs(difference.TotalMilliseconds) < 0)
    {
        throw new AssertFailedException("DateTime was not within the expected range from now.");
    }        
}
```

I'd like for the double-click to place me on the method call within the MyTest method, while it now places me on the throw within the AssertDateRange method.

Comment: Maybe just a rethrow to put it on the stack above?

Comment: Just added a code example to better illustrate.